# How to set the prototype of a JavaScript object that has already been instantiated?

Tags: javascript, function-prototypes

Suppose I have an object `foo` in my JavaScript code.  `foo` is a complex object and it is generated somewhere else.  How can I change the prototype of the `foo` object?

My motivation is setting appropriate prototypes to objects serialized from .NET to JavaScript literals.

Suppose that I've written the following JavaScript code within an ASP.NET page.

```
var foo = <%=MyData %>;
```

Suppose that `MyData` is the result of invoking the .NET `JavaScriptSerializer` on a `Dictionary<string,string>` object.

At run-time, this becomes the following:

```
var foo = [{"A":"1","B":"2"},{"X":"7","Y":"8"}];
```

As you can see, `foo` becomes an array of objects. I would like to be able to initialize `foo` with an appropriate prototype. I do *not* want to modify the `Object.prototype` nor `Array.prototype`.  How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to add to its existing prototype or switch it to a new prototype?

Comment: Do you mean make changes to the prototype - or actually change the prototype as in switch out one prototype and replace it with another.  I'm not even sure the later case is possible.

Comment: Do you mean the **explicit** prototype property or the **implicit** prototype link? (Those two are two very different things)

Comment: I was originally concerned with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013545/net-javascriptserializer-set-the-prototype-of-the-serialized-output

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're looking for, I highly advise that you not do it if you figure out how since it is bad practice + hard to debug. If you got the object elsewhere its functionality may depend on its prototype so you shouldn't be messing around with it. At best the solution you find will probably be browser-specific since I don't think this is supported by any Javascript standard.

Comment: Are you familiar with Backbone's `extend` or Google's `goog.inherit`? Many developers provide ways to build inheritance before calling the elderly `new` constructor—which is before we were given `Object.create` and didn't have to worry about overriding `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Why do you want to change the `prototype`? What are you trying to accomplish? I think changing the prototype is the wrong way to go (except for learning).

Answer (score 121, accepted):

##### **Update:** ES6 now specifies [Object.setPrototypeOf(object, prototype)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

How you use this depends on what "the new prototype" is based. Given some object `obj`:

1. if the new prototype is a plain object `something`, use `Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, something)`,
2. if the new prototype is based on an ES5-and-below-style constructor function `function Something() {...}` with its own corresponding `Something.prototype = {...}`, use `Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, Something.prototype)`,
3. and if the new prototype is an ES6 class `class Something { ... }`, use `Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, Something.prototype)`.

##### EDIT Feb. 2012: the answer below is no longer accurate.

`__proto__` is being added to ECMAScript 6 as "normative optional" which means it isn't required to be implemented but if it is, it must follow the given set of rules. This is currently unresolved but at least it will be officially part of JavaScript's specification.

This question is a lot more complicated than it seems on the surface, and beyond most peoples' pay grade in regards to knowledge of Javascript internals.

The `prototype` property of an object is used when creating new child objects of that object. Changing it does not reflect in the object itself, rather is reflected when that object is used as a constructor for other objects, and has no use in changing the prototype of an existing object.

```
function myFactory(){};
myFactory.prototype = someOtherObject;

var newChild = new myFactory;
newChild.__proto__ === myFactory.prototype === someOtherObject; //true
```

Objects have an internal [[prototype]] property which points to the current prototype. The way it works is whenever a property on an object is called it will start at the object and then go up through the [[prototype]] chain until it finds a match, or fail, after the root Object prototype. This is how Javascript allows for runtime building and modification of objects; it has a plan for searching for what it needs.

The `__proto__` property exists in some implementations (a lot now): any Mozilla implementation, all the webkit ones I know of, some others. This property points to the internal [[prototype]] property and allows modification post-creation on objects. Any properties and functions will instantly switch to match the prototype due to this chained lookup.

This feature, while being standardized now, still is not a required part of JavaScript, and in languages supporting it has a high likelihood of knocking your code down into the "unoptimized" category. JS engines have to do their best to classify code, especially "hot"  code which is accessed very often, and if you're doing something fancy like modifying `__proto__`, they won't optimize your code at all.

This posts https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=607863 specifically discusses current implementations of `__proto__` and the differences between them. Every implementation does it differently, because it's a hard and unsolved problem. Everything in Javascript is mutable, except a.) the syntax b.) host objects (the DOM exists outside Javascript technically) and c.) `__proto__`. The rest is completely in the hands of you and every other developer, so you can see why `__proto__` sticks out like a sore thumb.

There is one thing that `__proto__` allows for that is otherwise impossible to do: the designation of an objects prototype at runtime separate from its constructor. This is an important use case and is one of the primary reasons `__proto__` isn't already dead. It's important enough that it's been a serious discussion point in the formulation of Harmony, or soon to be known as ECMAScript 6. The ability to specify the prototype of an object during creation will be a part of the next version of Javascript and this will be the bell indicating `__proto__`'s days are formally numbered.

In the short term, you can use `__proto__` if you're targeting browsers that support it (not IE, and no IE ever will). It's likely it'll work in webkit and moz for the next 10 years as ES6 won't be finalized until 2013.

**Brendan Eich** - re:[Approach of new Object methods in ES5](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2010-April/010917.html):

> Sorry, ... but settable `__proto__`, apart from the object initialiser use case (i.e., on a new object not yet reachable, analogous to ES5's Object.create), is a terrible idea. I write this having designed and implemented settable `__proto__` over 12 years ago.
>
> ... the  lack of stratification is a problem (consider JSON data with a key `"__proto__"`). And worse, the mutability means implementations must check for cyclic prototype chains in order to avoid ilooping. *[constant checks for infinite recursion are required]*
>
> Finally, mutating `__proto__` on an existing object may break non-generic methods in the new prototype object, which cannot possibly work on the receiver (direct) object whose `__proto__` is being set. This is simply bad practice, a form of intentional type confusion, in general.

Comment: Excellent breakdown! While it's not quite the same thing as a mutable prototype, ECMA Harmony will probably implement [proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies), which let you shim additional functionality onto particular objects using a catchall pattern.

Comment: Brendan Eich's issue is native to prototyping languages as a whole. Possibly making \_\_proto\_\_ `non-writable, configurable` would remedy these concerns by forcing the user to explicitly reconfigure the property. In the end, bad practices are associated with the abuses of a language's capabilities, not the capabilities themselves. Writable \_\_proto\_\_ is not unheard-of. There are many other non-enumerable writable properties and, while there are dangers, there are best practices as well. The head of a hammer should not be removed simply because it can be used improperly to wound someone.

Comment: Mutating `__proto__` is needed, because Object.create will only produce Objects, not functions for example, nor Symbols, Regexes, DOM elements or other host objects. If you want your objects to be callable, or special in other ways, but still change their prototype chain, you are stuck without settable `__proto__` or Proxies

Comment: It would be better if it was not done with a magical property though but instead with Object.setPrototype, eliminating the "`__proto__` in JSON" concern.
Brendan Eich's other concerns are laughable. Recursive prototype chains or using a prototype with inadequate methods for the given object are programmer errors, not language faults and should not be a factor, and besides they can happen with Object.create just as well as with freely settable `__proto__`.

Comment: IE 10 supports `__proto__`.

Comment: You wrote : _Everything in Javascript is mutable except the syntax, host objects and `__proto__`_ .All primitives in javascript are also immutable, see : http://www.2ality.com/2011/03/javascript-values-not-everything-is.html#comment-1718708663

Comment: As of February 2016, doing the following: `function A(){}; var a=new A(); var sth = {name: 'new proto'}; A.prototype=a.__proto__=sth;` produces `a isinstanceof A // true` on both Chrome and Firefox, but `a.name // 'new proto'` on Chrome and `a.name // undefined` on Firefox

Comment: @Mike re your edit, I don't see why you distinguish between ES5 and ES6 classes. You'd use `Something.prototype` for both, you shouldn't invoke the constructor

Comment: oops, was thinking of ES5 inheritance - fixed.

Answer (score 38):

ES6 finally specifies [Object.setPrototypeOf(object, prototype)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) which is already implemented in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `constructor` on an instance of an object to alter the prototype of an object in-place. I believe this is what you're asking to do.

This means if you have `foo` which is an instance of `Foo`:

```
function Foo() {}

var foo = new Foo();
```

You can add a property `bar` to all instances of `Foo` by doing the following:

```
foo.constructor.prototype.bar = "bar";
```

Here's a fiddle showing the proof-of-concept: http://jsfiddle.net/C2cpw/. Not terribly sure how older browsers will fare using this approach, but I'm pretty sure this should do the job pretty well.

If your intention is to mixin functionality into objects, this snippet should do the job:

```
function mix() {
  var mixins = arguments,
      i = 0, len = mixins.length;

  return {
    into: function (target) {
      var mixin, key;

      if (target == null) {
        throw new TypeError("Cannot mix into null or undefined values.");
      }

      for (; i < len; i += 1) {
        mixin = mixins[i];
        for (key in mixin) {
          target[key] = mixin[key];
        }

        // Take care of IE clobbering `toString` and `valueOf`
        if (mixin && mixin.toString !== Object.prototype.toString) {
          target.toString = mixin.toString;
        } else if (mixin && mixin.valueOf !== Object.prototype.valueOf) {
          target.valueOf = mixin.valueOf;
        }
      }
      return target;
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: +1: This is informative and interesting, but doesn't really help me get what I want.  I am updating my question to be more specific.

Comment: You could also use `foo.__proto__.bar = 'bar';`

Answer (score 10):

You can do `foo.__proto__ = FooClass.prototype`, AFAIK that's supported by Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Keep in mind that the `__proto__` property is non-standard and might go away at some point.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto. Also see http://www.mail-archive.com/jsmentors@googlegroups.com/msg00392.html for an explanation why there is no `Object.setPrototypeOf()` and why `__proto__` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You could define your proxy constructor function and then create a new instance and copy all the properties from the original object to it.

```
// your original object
var obj = { 'foo': true };

// your constructor - "the new prototype"
function Custom(obj) {
    for ( prop in obj ) {
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
            this[prop] = obj[prop];
        }
    }
}

// the properties of the new prototype
Custom.prototype.bar = true;

// pass your original object into the constructor
var obj2 = new Custom(obj);

// the constructor instance contains all properties from the original 
// object and also all properties inherited by the new prototype
obj2.foo; // true
obj2.bar; // true
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6Xq3P/

The `Custom` constructor represents the new prototype, ergo, its `Custom.prototype` object contains all the new properties which you'd like to use with your original object.

Inside the `Custom` constructor, you just copy all the properties from the original object to the new instance object.

This new instance object contains all the properties from the original object (they were copied to it inside the constructor), and also all the new properties defined inside `Custom.prototype` (because the new object is a `Custom` instance).

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the prototype of a JavaScript object that has already been instantiated in a cross browser way.  As others have mentioned, your options include:

1. changing the non standard/cross browser `__proto__` property
2. Copy the Objects properties to a new object

Neither are particularly great, especially if you have to recursively loop through an object into inner objects to effectively change an elements entire prototype.

#### Alternative solution to question

I'm going to take a more abstract look at the functionality it appears you desire.

Basically prototype/methods just allow for a way to group functions based on an object.
Instead of writing

```
function trim(x){ /* implementation */ }
trim('   test   ');
```

you write

```
'   test  '.trim();
```

The above syntax has been coined the term OOP because of the object.method() syntax.
Some of OOPs main advantage over traditional functional programming includes:

1. Short methods names and fewer variables `obj.replace('needle','replaced')` vs having to remember names like `str_replace ( 'foo' , 'bar' , 'subject')` and the location of the different variables
2. method chaining(`string.trim().split().join()`) is a potentially easier to modify and write  then nested functions `join(split(trim(string))`

Unfortunately in JavaScript (as shown above) you can't modify an already existent prototype.  Ideally above you could modify `Object.prototype` for only the given Object's above, but unfortunately modifying `Object.prototype` would potentially break scripts (resulting in property collision and overriding).

There is no commonly used middle ground between these 2 styles of programming, and no OOP way to organize custom functions.

[UnlimitJS](http://limeblack.github.com/UnlimitJS/) provides a middle ground that allows you to define custom methods.  It avoids:

1. Property collision, because it doesn't extend Objects' prototypes
2. Still allows for an OOP chaining syntax
3. It is 450 byte cross browser(IE6+,Firefox 3.0+,Chrome,Opera,Safari 3.0+) script that Unlimit's much of JavaScript's prototype property collision issues

Using your code above I would simply create a namespace of functions that you intend to call against the object.

Here is an example:

```
var foo = [{"A":"1","B":"2"},{"X":"7","Y":"8"}];

// define namespace with methods
var $ = {
  log:function(){
    console.log(this);
    return this;
  }[Unlimit](),
  alert:function(){
    alert(''+this);
  }[Unlimit]()
}


foo[$.log]()
   [$.log]()
   [$.alert]();
```

You can read more of the examples here [UnlimitJS](http://limeblack.github.com/UnlimitJS/).  Basically when you call `[Unlimit]()` on a function, it allows for the function to be called as a method on an Object.  It's like a middle ground between the OOP and functional roads.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the `[[prototype]]` reference of already-constructed objects, as far as I know. You could alter the the prototype property of the original constructor function but, as you've already commented, that constructor is `Object`, and altering core JS constructs is a Bad Thing.

You could create a proxy object of the constructed object that implements the additional functionality that you need, though. You could also monkeypatch the additional methods and behaviors by assigning directly to the object in question.

Perhaps you can get what you want some other way, if you're willing to approach from a different angle: What do you need to do that involves messing with the prototype?

Comment: Can anyone else comment on the accuracy of this?

Comment: It appears, based on [this terrible jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWDBH/) that you can alter the prototype of an existing object by altering its `__proto__` property. This will only work in browsers that support the `__proto__` notation, which is Chrome and Firefox, and it has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). So, in short, you can change the `[[prototype]]` of an object, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @NickHusher Wrong now. You can alter prototype of existing object. Instead of `__proto__` use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` / `Object.setPrototypeOf()`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the prototype, why not injecting it in the code?

```
var foo = new MyPrototype(<%= MyData %>);
```

So, once the data is serialized, you get

```
var foo = new MyPrototype([{"A":"1","B":"2"},{"X":"7","Y":"8"}]);
```

now you only need a constructor that takes an array as argument.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to really inherit from `Array` or "sub-class" it.

What you can do is this (**WARNING: FESTERING CODE AHEAD**):

```
function Foo(arr){
  [].push.apply(this, arr)
}
Foo.prototype = []
Foo.prototype.something = 123

var foo = new Foo(<%=MyData %>)

foo.length // => 2
foo[0] // => {"A":"1","B":"2"}
foo.something // => 123
```

This works, but will cause certain trouble for anyone that crosses it's path (it looks like an array, but things will go wrong if you try manipulating it).

Why don't you go the sane route and add methods/properties directly to `foo`, or use a constructor and save your array as a property?

```
function Foo(arr){
  this.items = arr
}
Foo.prototype = {
  someMethod : function(){ ... }
  //...
}

var foo = new Foo(<%=MyData %>)
foo.items // => [{"A":"1","B":"2"},{"X":"7","Y":"8"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create prototype on the fly, this is one of the way

```
function OntheFlyProto (info){
    this.items = info;
    this.y =-1;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length ; i++){
        OntheFlyProto.prototype["get"+this.items[i].name] = function (){
            this.y++;
            return this.items[this.y].value;
        }
    }
}

var foo = [{name:"one", value:1},{name:"two", value:2}];
v = new OntheFlyProto(foo);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foo.prototype.myFunction = function(){alert("me");}
```

Comment: No, you can't.  That's a static property.

Comment: @SLaks `prototype` is static? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: `prototype` is a property of a function, not an object.  `Object.prototype` exists; `{}.prototype` doesn't.

Comment: If you don't care about browser compatibility, you can use `Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)` to get the constructor prototype object. You can modify the properties on that to modify the prototype of the object. It only works in recent browsers, couldn't tell you which ones, though.

Comment: @TeslaNick: You could just go and modify `Object.prototype` directly because that's most likely what `Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)` will return. Not very useful.

Comment: @Wladimir: If you don't have a reference to the original constructor function (as is implied in the original question by, "complex and generated somewhere else"), `Object.getPrototypeOf` is the only standards-based way of getting a reference to that object.

Comment: @TeslaNick: I was trying to say that we are likely dealing with an object that's inheriting from `Object` directly, not from some custom class (otherwise setting the prototype wouldn't make much sense). And changing the prototype for all objects isn't something one is likely to want.