# Good way to change an object's prototype to change results of instanceof?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-harmony

I wanted to comment on [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015693/how-to-set-the-prototype-of-a-javascript-object-that-has-already-been-instantiat), but it appears to be locked.

Here is my use case:

1. An object `obj` is created with constructor `Base`. `obj instanceof Base` returns true.
2. I want to change the prototype of `obj` such that it appears as if `obj` was constructed from `Derived`. That is, I want

   - `obj` to get access to the methods of `Derived`
   - `obj instanceof Derived` to return true

The reason is that `obj` is to have a type in the hierarchy that is unknown at the time of its creation and determined by what happens after. I want to be able to move it down the hierarchy.

I believe I can do this with

`obj.__proto__ = Derived.prototype;`

but `__proto__` will be deprecated in the next version of JavaScript. The [proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:direct_proxies) API, which has changed since the question I linked above was asked, does not seem to support my use case.

Is there an alternative implementation for my use case that exists now or is planned for the future?

The only alternative I can see right now is to use

```
obj2 = Object.create(Derived.prototype);
obj2.extend(obj);
```

and never store more than one reference to obj, but that cost is quite an inconvenience.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJzC7/1/) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: `__proto__` is [already deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto). You can only modify an object's `[[Prototype]]` when you construct it, you can't modify the chain afterward.

Comment: Ok... and yet it is still available in my environment. I am looking for a more portable solution. Can you help with that?

Comment: Something that is deprecated isn't removed from the system, it is essentially marked for future deletion and therefore should not be used. Support is maintained to allow time for code that uses deprecated features to be modified.

Comment: Yes, and what is the point of mentioning that? I already mentioned I am currently relying on non-portable behavior and am searching for an alternative. Your comment has contributed nothing to the discussion.

Comment: Ok, it seemed you were surprised to find a deprecated feature still available, just thought I'd explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no possibility to do that. As RobG demonstrated, you can make instanceof returning `false` by <s>changing</s> harming the class's `prototype` property.

Seeing that, I thought you could do it with an extra class, you know, like the `F` from the common `Object.create` shim:

```
Object.newChangeable = function create(b) {
    function F(){b.call(this);}
    F.prototype = b.prototype;
    var f = new F();
    f.change = function change(n) {
        F.prototype = n.prototype;
    };
    return f;
}

var obj = Object.newChangeable(Base);
obj instanceof Base; // true

obj.change(Derived);
```

But **no**:

```
obj instanceof Derived; // still false
obj instanceof Base; // still true
```

because the internal [[Prototype]] of `obj` still points to the same as `Base.prototype`. What you can do is making `Derived` the new `Base`:

```
var obj = new Base;
obj instanceof Base; // true

Derived.prototype = Base.prototype;
Base.prototype = {}; // something else

alert(obj instanceof Derived); // true
alert(obj instanceof Base); // false
```

But I don't think that is what you wanted, manipulating the right side of the expression instead of changing something at `obj` :-)

Comment: Ok, I think you could have stopped after the first sentence. I'm going to give some more time for other ideas, but I'll accept this if no one else can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The *instanceof* operator just checks if a constructor's public `prototype` property is on an object's `[[Prototype]]` chain. One way to break the chain is to change the constructor's prototype:

```
function Base() {}

var base = new Base();

alert( base instanceof Base); // true

Base.prototype = {};

alert( base instanceof Base); // false
alert( base instanceof Object); // true
```

The second alert is false because the new `Base.prototype` is not on the `[[Prototype]]` chain of `base` any more (the original one still is though). Note that `Object.protoyype` still is. The above is one reason why the `instanceof` operator is not seen as being particularly useful.

To do what you are trying to do, you must create the `[[Prototype]]` chain when the object is constructed because you can't change it later:

```
Derived.prototype = new Base();

var base = new Derived();

alert(base instanceof Base); // true
alert(base instanceof Derived); // true
```

#### Edit

The requirements were:

> 1. An object obj is created with constructor Base. obj instanceof Base returns true.

As shown, that isn't necessarily true. If you have a strategy that depends on `instanceof` returning a particular value then you are placing a (probably unreasonable) constraint on the design with no clear benefit.

> `2`. I want to change the prototype of obj such that it appears as if obj was constructed from Derived. That is, I want
>
> •obj to get access to the methods of Derived

you can do that by making Base.prototype an instance of Derived (as shown) or by copying the properties to Base.prototype.

> •obj instanceof Derived to return true

You can do that by making `Base.prototype` an instance of *Derived* **before** creating any instances of *Base*.

You can't modify the chain after an instance is created. If you drop the `instanceof` constraint, then you can add the methods of `Derived.prototype` by simply copying them to `Base.prototype`. Another way is using *call* or *apply*:

```
Derived.prototype.someMethod.call(base, ...);
```

but I suspect you are trying to do something that is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I would have done that too. But I thought the question was about specific instances, and this solution changes the prototypes of the whole "class".

Comment: Bergi is correct. Please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJzC7/1/) I added to the question.

Comment: But your fiddle doesn't do the above, it assigns a new prototype to Derived but then still makes an instance of Base (which does not connect the prototypes as you want).

Comment: Derived gets a prototype assigned so that instances of it will be derived from Base. It changes the prototype chain of obj to accomplish the two criteria I specified.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this (a little bit confused about the question and I'm still a learner)

```
function vehicle(name, color)
{
    if(this instanceof arguments.callee)
    {    
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }
    else return new arguments.callee(arguments);   
}

vehicle.prototype = {
    getName : function()
    {
        alert(this.name);
    } 
}

function Car(name, color, speed)
{
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.speed = speed;
}

Car.prototype = vehicle();
var obj = new Car("Ford", "Red", "200mph");

obj.getName(); // alerts `Ford` using vehicle's/parent's method
alert(obj instanceof vehicle); alerts `True` instanceof vehicle's/parent's constructor
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PXvpc/3/).

An article by [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/).

Comment: No, the question was "how to make a `new car()` instanceof `plane`?"!

Comment: @ Bergi, Here vehicle is base constructor and car is derived from vehicle and Ford is an object created by car , so what did you mean by plane here, please ?

Comment: Sheikh, I thought I explained clearly in the original question, but I will try again: You created obj as an instance of Car. Now create a new class Dragster that derives from Car, and change obj (but not its construction from Car) so that this expression returns true: "obj instanceof Dragster"

Comment: Let me grasp it, will be back soon.

Comment: But then I cannot use a different prototype for Dragster without changing Car, so no, it is not ok.

Comment: +1, what you're doing there is just renaming Car to Dragster.

Comment: If you find any better answer please inform me, heerasheikh@ymail.com and all the best.

Comment: Learning is not over my friend, a long way to go, hope I can learn something new from this one. Everyday I'm learning something new from So.