# Cannot set instance prototype using prototype = in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, ecmascript-5, prototypal-inheritance

I'm struggling to set the instance of a protype. I've got something like this:

```
function Course() {
    // Some stuff
}

Course.prototype.MyMethod = function() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Now if I create a `New Course()`, all works fine, however, I'm getting the Courses from `JSON`. So what I wanted to do is:

```
data.forEach(function(courseFromJSON) {
    courseFromJSON.prototype = Course.prototype;
    courseFromJSON.prototype = new Course(); // Doesn't work either
});
```

But my courses never get the method `MyMethod` set to them. Neither is setting `courseFromJSON.prototype` to `new Course()`. I've been going through Douglas Crockford's video's, but can't seem to get it right. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015693/how-to-set-the-prototype-of-a-javascript-object-that-has-already-been-instantiat

Comment: Thanks @Vandesh, I had read that, the code uses the .prototype = something, which is what I tried. But it also states, that it only reflects on the child instances. Question remains: how do I get my prototype methods working on stuff incoming from JSON?

Comment: ok, so courseFromJSON.__proto__ = Course.prototype seems to work

Comment: and why it works, is mentioned too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code wasn't working because you can't change the prototype of an already created object, or at least not via the `prototype` property.

Two alternatives exist:

1. Use the internal `__proto__` property, but this is not recommended because it is a non-standard property.
2. Use the [`setPrototypeOf(Object, prototype)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) function, this is recommended and will be standardized in ES6.

Or even better, use the code snippet taken from the documentation link on `setPrototypeOf()`:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf = Object.setPrototypeOf || function (obj, proto) {
    obj.__proto__ = proto;
    return obj; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, especially for the recommendation on which option to use.