# How to set the prototype of a function?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

Something like this, but not using `__proto__`:

```
var o = {
    i :2
}; 

var f1 = function(){
    alert(f1.i);
} 

f1.__proto__ = o; 

o.i = 3; 

f1(); //3
```

This question have not an answer here: [How to set the prototype of a JavaScript object that has already been instantiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015693/how-to-set-the-prototype-of-a-javascript-object-that-has-already-been-instantiat)

Comment: When I see such questions I always wonder: why do you people intentionally try to make your code as hard for understanding and maintenance as possible?

Comment: No, the function may not already been declared.

Comment: @D_Pavel: You're trying to set the internal prototype of a function object that doesn't yet exist?

Comment: @D_Pavel: why "*like this, but not using `__proto__`*"? What are you trying to do here in the first place, what is your use case?

Comment: the function object may be already exist or not.

Comment: I'm trying to set `__proto__` of a function.

Comment: At the end must be: myFunction.__proto__ === myObject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87574/discussion-between-d-pavel-and-bergi).

Answer (score 0):

One method is using [bind API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). So your Javascript looks like this

```
var o = {i :2}; 
var f1 = function(){    alert(this.i);    }.bind(o)
o.i = 3; 
f1(); //3
```

Comment: bind not set the `__proto__`

Comment: @D_Pavel and in your question you did not ask to set it.