# adding method during object.prototype.render but in another .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Website - Wordpress

Plugin used - https://github.com/tomharrigan/transporter

Plugin Js file - https://github.com/tomharrigan/transporter/blob/master/transporter.js

Line No 121 of the `JS` file

```
/**
 * Renders the results from a successful response.
 */
Scroller.prototype.render = function( response ) {
    this.body.addClass( 'infinity-success' );

    // Check if we can wrap the html
    this.element.append( response.html );

    this.body.trigger( 'post-load', response );
    this.ready = true;
}
```

Basically i want to modify some of the my html `before` the data is appended

The only problem is i cannot modify the plugin `Js` file as it may get a update and all the changes will get lost

Is it possible to extend the plugin in another `JS` file?

```
/**
 * Renders the results from a successful response.
 */
Scroller.prototype.render = function( response ) {
    this.body.addClass( 'infinity-success' );

    // changed html
    this.element.find('.infinite-wrap .loading-message').html('Next post is loaded');

    // Check if we can wrap the html
    this.element.append( response.html );

    this.body.trigger( 'post-load', response );
    this.ready = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not well versed in object oriented javascript (yet :D), but can this help: [How to set the prototype of a JavaScript object that has already been instantiated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015693/how-to-set-the-prototype-of-a-javascript-object-that-has-already-been-instantiat)

Comment: What do you mean you "cannot modify the js as it may get an update and all the changes will get lost?" cant you download the file and make the changes in that file?

Comment: In wordpress there are [plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins) eample of [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) check the **Last Updated: xx days ago** for each plugin and on each update something new is implemented in that plugin by the plugin developer check the [changelog](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bbpress/changelog/) and during this update process all the files are updated @mrapsogos

Comment: yes but you can download a certain version and make the changes you need based on that version. What is the problem with this?

Comment: It should not be that way @mrapsogos