# Adding prototype functions back to returned Google Maps API object when using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, prototype, stringify

I'm try to take two locations, find the directions between the two points using `directionsService.route` in the Google Maps API, and then store the directions object I'm returned in localStorage for later use. I'm trying to use the solution below (for a somewhat unrelated problem) but its failing on the last two lines because `.extend()`, `.getNorthEast()`, and `.getSouthWest()` are stored in prototype of the Google object. These methods help set the bounds of the new map when combining multiple trips.

https://lemonharpy.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/working-around-8-waypoint-limit-in-google-maps-directions-api/

```
if (count == 0) {
    combinedResults = unsortedResults[key].result;
} else {
    // only building up legs, overview_path, and bounds in my consolidated object. This is not a complete 
    // directionResults object, but enough to draw a path on the map, which is all I need
    combinedResults.routes[0].legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].legs);
    combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path = combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].overview_path);
    combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getNorthEast());
    combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getSouthWest());
}
```

I've tried several workarounds to save prototype functions when you run through the `JSON.stringify()` to `JSON.parse()` conversion but nothing works.

**Update**

I tried using this [add-on](http://www.onegeek.com.au/projects/javascript-serialization) to help retain the prototype functions, which it does, but I don't think its possible to re-add these functions back into the JS object after its been serialized/deserialized as the object has already been [initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015693/how-to-set-the-prototype-of-a-javascript-object-that-has-already-been-instantiat)

```
var serializer = new ONEGEEK.GSerializer();
var s = serializer.serialize(result.routes[0].bounds);
var d = serializer.deserialize(s);
```

What I ended up doing was a bit of a hackish work-around to mimick the `bounds.extend()` function that required some prototype functions (below). The only problem with this solution is if I need to interact with the cached objects for anything else I'll be in the same position

```
var existing = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds;
var adding = trip2.routes[0].bounds;

existing.north = existing.north > adding.north ? existing.north : adding.north;  
existing.south = existing.south < adding.south ? existing.south : adding.south;  
existing.east = existing.east > adding.east ? existing.east : adding.east;
existing.west = existing.west < adding.west ? existing.west : adding.west;
```

Comment: How are you reconstructing the bounds objects?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue **in the question** (not an external link).

Comment: I updated my answer. I think the only way of reconstructing the bounds object properly would be to save all the variables the `bounds.extend` would need before you serialize it and then try and reconstruct the original function after.

Comment: No it wouldn't.  A bounds object is defined by its SouthWest and NorthEast corners.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's not possible to store functions in JSON at all.

What you would have to do to restore the original `LatLngBounds` is simply creating a `new LatLngBounds()` by using the stored LatLngBoundsLiteral as argument:
e.g.

```
var json=JSON.parse(//stored string
                    '{"bounds:{"south":41.9029,"west":2.3,"north":55.7,"east":37.6}}');
json.bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds(json.bounds);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty similar to what I ended up doing. My goal here is to cut down on the Google API query limit problem so I was able to just mimic the bounds functionality I needed.