# Can the prototype of an object be changed to another object?

Tags: javascript, prototype

When an object is created, its prototype is also set to an object.

After an object is created, can its prototype be changed to a different object?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015693/how-to-set-the-prototype-of-a-javascript-object-that-has-already-been-instantiat (though the answer here is better imo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) (link has some useful warnings as well):

```js
let parent = {
    test: "hello"
}

let child = {}
// object
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(child))

Object.setPrototypeOf(child, parent)
// parent now prototype
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(child))

// can access parent props
console.log(child.hasOwnProperty('test')) // not on child object
console.log(child.test)
```